# Is it feasible to have two instances of the same spark job to processing Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a data enrichment job and enrich my data from data source(one kafka topic) then publish to another sink (kafka topic) after processing. 
The job itself is IO bound and the processing speed is not increasing linearly when I add more CPU/Memory. 
Should I horizontally scale up the jobs with two or three instances and let them consume the same Kafka topic with same groupId?

The difficulty is that currently my codes is maintaining the processing offset in kafka broker. So I will have below codes adding an extra parameters to define which partitions to load into the RDD and let the high level decide which offset they need to read. And this looks like not that good.

```
  private def loadRdd[T:ClassTag](maxMessages: Long = 0, messageFormatter: ((String, String)) => T)
                             (implicit inputConfig: Config): (RDD[T], Unit => Unit, Boolean) = {
val brokersConnectionString = Try(inputConfig.getString("brokersConnectionString")).getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Fail to retrieve the broker connection string."))
val topic                   = inputConfig.getString("topic")
val groupId                 = inputConfig.getString("groupId")
val retriesAttempts         = Try(inputConfig.getInt("retries.attempts")).getOrElse(SparkKafkaProviderUtilsFunctions.DEFAULT_RETRY_ATTEMPTS)
val retriesDelay            = Try(inputConfig.getInt("retries.delay")).getOrElse(SparkKafkaProviderUtilsFunctions.DEFAULT_RETRY_DELAY) * 1000

val topicOffsetRanges = KafkaClusterUtils.getTopicOffsetRanges(inputConfig, topic, SparkKafkaProviderUtilsFunctions.getDebugLogger(inputConfig)).toList
                                         .map { case (partitionId, (minOffset, maxOffset)) => OffsetRange(topic, partitionId, minOffset, maxOffset) }.toArray

val (offsetRanges, readAllAvailableMessages) = restrictOffsetRanges(topicOffsetRanges, maxMessages)

val rdd: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = RetryUtils.retryOrDie(retriesAttempts, retryDelay = retriesDelay, loopFn = {SparkLogger.warn("Failed to create Spark RDD, retrying...")},
                                failureFn = { SparkLogger.warn("Failed to create Spark RDD, giving up...")})(
  KafkaUtils.createRDD(sc, KafkaClusterUtils.getKafkaConsumerParameters(brokersConnectionString, groupId), offsetRanges, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent))

(rdd.map(pair => messageFormatter(pair.key(), pair.value())), Unit => commitOffsets(offsetRanges, inputConfig), readAllAvailableMessages)
```

}

Should I proceed with this direction and let the high level decide which partitions belongs to which job instance? Or I should simply scale up with adding more CPU and memory?

Thanks!

Comment: May be you should use Spark Streaming API and let it manages automatically the Kafka offsets? (use a Checkpoint to save context). You can specify how many Spark workers to run but a good practice is to allocate one worker per Kafka partition.

Comment: Thanks @Harold! We tried the Spark streaming before and it always pick up latest offset if the job restart. So we got some case missing data.    Between last time the job stop and restart.

Comment: If you save the offsets with a Checkpoint https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/spark-streaming-checkpoint/ on HDFS and configure Kafka consumer witj auto.offset.reset=earliest, you should not loose any message.